# Check if a string is the same after word reordering - C#

Tags: c#

Here is a string: `-A -P -O`

Now we have the same but in another order: `-P -A -O`

What is the best way of detecting that these two strings are the same?

Comment: You are missing [mcve]

Comment: `[theFirst].Split().Except([theSecond].Split())`

Comment: A string "-A -P -O" can never be the same as a string "-P -A -O".

Comment: please be more precise in the definition of **same**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var setA = "-A -P -O".Split(' ');
var setB = "-P -A -O".Split(' ');
var areSetsEqual = setA.Except(setB).Count() == 0 && setB.Except(setA).Count() == 0;
```

Comment: Nice and correct if and only if neither string have *duplicates*, otherwise there's a *counter example*: `"-A -P -O -A"` vs. `-A -P -O -P"` expected `false`, actual `true`.

Answer (score 3):

You can just split both strings using `Split` method, sort the arrays using `Array.Sort` and then compare the two resulting arrays using `SequenceEqual` method.

Comment: ... Or Linq: `bool result = left.Split(' ').OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(right.Split(' ').OrderBy(x => x));`

Answer (score 2):

You could try this code:

```
public bool CheckString(string s1, string s2)
{
  var firstArray = s1.Split(' ').ToArray();
  var secondArray = s2.Split(' ').ToArray();
  Array.Sort(firstArray);
  Array.Sort(secondArray);
  if (firstArray.Length != secondArray.Length) return false;
  for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length; i++)
    if (firstArray[i] != secondArray[i]) return false;
  return true;
}
```